# Retrieve the common values from multiple array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Retrieve the common value 12 from given array

**Example:** **Input** like:

```
[ [12, 6],[12, 11, 9, 8, 1],[12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1],[12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1],[12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1] ]
```

My expected **Output** to be :

```
[12]
```

Comment: Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: var d = function(){
    var min = 1000; var arg = 0; var index = 0; 
    var common = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        if(arguments[i].length < min){
            min = arguments[i].length;
            arg = i;}
    }for (var i=0; i<arguments[arg].length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j<arguments.length; j++){
            if(j!=arg && arguments[j].indexOf(arguments[arg][i]) != -1){
                index++;}
        }if(index == arguments.length-1){
            common.push(arguments[arg][i]);}
        index = 0;}
    return common;};

Comment: If you pass the arrays in the function it returns the unique value,but here we need to split the arrays like

Comment: like d([1,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,4]) but i want to send the data to the function as one array

Comment: I need solution that's it,I am not content writer to write and ask a perfect question.Any way thanks for your valuable advice @JeroenHeier

Comment: @sindhujaThiyagarajan FYI, if someone ask you the same question, will you solve? And we are here to help you but not just you dump the question and we will give you the answer.

Comment: @Durga please see the above comments,Yeah I know that I'm not good in english, and I don't know to ask questions.But this not a way to treat me right?? Please guys don't dominate others. I no need anyone of your help. And nice treating website guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array = [[12, 6], [12, 11, 9, 8, 1], [12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1], [12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1], [12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1]],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(c => b.includes(c)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach should be as follows:

**Pseudocode:**

```
commonArray = clone(allArrays[0])
for i in 1, length(allArrays) do:
    removeIfNotExists(initialArray, allArrays[i])
```

removeIfNotExists can be have a logic like:

```
removeIfNotExists(commonArray, checkArray):
    for(index in commonArray):
        if(commonArray[index] not in checkArray):
            delete commonArray[index]
```

You basically need to remove every element from common array which is not present in the check array. Doing this n times will result in commonArray having elements which are common across all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array & then use `reduce` method to calculate the occurrence of each items. Then loop through that object and update the variable with element which have highest occurrence.

```js
var x = [
  [12, 6],
  [12, 11, 9, 8, 1],
  [12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1],
  [12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1],
  [12, 11, 9, 8, 6, 1]
]

// flattening the array and reducing to single object
var flatObj = [].concat.apply([], x).reduce(function(a, b) {
    // the object have same key update the count or add a new key
    a[b] = "undefined" == typeof a[b] ? 1 : a[b] + 1;
    return a;
  }, Object.create(null)),
  highestValue = 0,
  num, keys;
//looping through the newly created object
for (keys in flatObj) {
  updating variable with the values
  flatObj[keys] > highestValue && (highestValue = flatObj[keys], num = keys);
}
console.log([Number(num)]);
```